# Change all elements in Numpy array that end up as individual arrays to floats Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array in which all of the elements in the array are also arrays:

```
a = [[array([ 4.15167139]) array([ 2.80260218]) array([ 3.34189103])
  array([ 3.73434426]) array([ 3.76504973]) array([ 3.91946708])
  array([ 2.850741]) array([ 1.9985034]) array([ 4.05191836])
  array([ 3.46145848]) array([ 2.99489689]) array([ 2.60462582])
  array([ 1.91031189]) array([ 2.90006744]) array([ 3.69799451])
  array([ 3.83314665]) array([ 4.42917628]) array([ 5.17647658])
  array([ 4.63462677]) array([ 4.69085313]) array([ 4.84746095])
  array([ 5.04396694]) array([ 5.10152712]) array([ 3.33442499])
  array([ 4.87380637]) ...]]
```

I want this to be the same shape array that it is now (20,96) but instead of all of the elements within this array being arrays I would just like them to be floats:

```
 a = [[ 4.15167139  2.80260218  3.34189103...4.87380637 ...]]
```

What is the best way to iterate over this array and change all of the elements from individual arrays to floats?

Comment: Try a mix of indexing to remove extra [], and `concatenate` (or `stack`) to join arrays.

Comment: how was this array created? I think modifying its creation directly might be easier... and probably cleaner.

Comment: how about `a=np.array(a).astype(np.float)`?

Comment: However you made this array, you did something wrong. You should address the problem at the source.

Comment: Sometimes lists of arrays, or object arrays of arrays are produced by other modules, and you have to make the best of it.

Answer (score 1):

Use indexing to remove a top layer of []

```
In [159]: array=np.array
In [161]: a = [[array([ 4.15167139]), array([ 2.80260218]), array([ 3.34189103]),
     ...:   array([ 3.73434426]), array([ 3.76504973]), array([ 3.91946708])]]
In [162]: len(a)
Out[162]: 1
In [163]: len(a[0])
Out[163]: 6
```

Use `concatenate` or `stack` to join a list of arrays.

```
In [164]: np.stack(a[0])
Out[164]: 
array([[ 4.15167139],
       [ 2.80260218],
       [ 3.34189103],
       [ 3.73434426],
       [ 3.76504973],
       [ 3.91946708]])
In [165]: np.concatenate(a[0])
Out[165]: 
array([ 4.15167139,  2.80260218,  3.34189103,  3.73434426,  3.76504973,
        3.91946708])
```

Reshape as needed.

In this case `np.array` also works, but I found that the `concatenate` approach is more reliable.  Sometimes `np.array` just produces an object array.

```
In [166]: np.array(a[0])
Out[166]: 
array([[ 4.15167139],
       [ 2.80260218],
       [ 3.34189103],
       [ 3.73434426],
       [ 3.76504973],
       [ 3.91946708]])
```

Comment: In[161] for ipython 3.5 (windows) gives error, `TypeError: array() argument 1 must be a unicode character, not list`. How to create such array?

Comment: I had to define an alias; `array = np.array`.  Notice I also added commas.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that `np.concatenate` is more reliable as said in hpaulj's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44917854/7738328), but in the current case `np.array` makes for a simpler solution, as it retains the dimensions. Applying it directly at the current array, will add a third dimension, however. This can be removed by slicing as:

```
b = np.array(a)[:,:,0]
```

It does not have to be more complicated than that.